# Publishing tools fails to start: Error: service failed to start System.PublishingTools.GPServer: <machine> Service's containing process has crashed

Tags: arcgis-server

My question is about PublishingTools failing to start.

The publishing tools service fails with the error message:

> "service failed to start System.PublishingTools.GPServer: 
>   Service's containing process has crashed"

I have uninstaled the Spectre and Meltdown security patches as well but the problem still exists.

The server logs give an error code 9003 with message

> Cannot obtain a free instance.; nested exception is:
>   com.esri.arcgis.discovery.ejb.ArcGISServerEJBException:
>   java.lang.Exception: Could not initialize service
>   'System/PublishingTools.GPServer'.

How do I fix this issue?

I have ArcGIS Server 10.1 on Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Ouch. You're using a *really ancient* build of ArcGIS Server. I found 10.2.2 to be relatively stable, but I had to rebuild my 10.1 installs on a quarterly basis, sometimes semi-quarterly. By comparison, my modern AGS installs (10.4.1+) only get rebuilt by upgrade. Without access to Esri Tech Support, rebuild is your only option here.

Comment: Thanks Vince, by rebuilding do you uninstall and install or do you simply do a repair

Comment: It's usually just the config-store which is corrupt, but I've also had to go as far as having Windows re-imaged. I've never used Repair.

Comment: Hello Vince, I dont understand how you do a rebuild. Can you advise how its done

Comment: There are too many permutations, any of which could further corrupt your machine if done incorrectly. If you understood the components of an ArcGIS Server installation well enough to easily fix this on your own, my hints should have been enough. There's a lot of documentation online, even for retired products, so it's still possible to learn what you need to fix this issue, but I can't provide non-Tech Support tech support in comments in GIS SE.